# What's the correct way to prorpely run a React file into a Html file?

Tags: html, reactjs

I recently learned React and I tried to practice what I learned, I made a container App that would render a div with a form and its children to an HTML file

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
class App extends React.Component () {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
    }
    mainDiv () {
            return (
                <form id="quote-box">
                    <p id="text"></p>     
                    <div>
                        <span id="author"></span>
                        <button id="quoteButton">New Quote</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            )
    }

    render() { return (<mainDiv/>)}
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />,  document.getElementById("root"));
```

it wasn't rendering so I tried changing its extension from jsx to Js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>random-quote-machine</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/babel" src="react.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it still did not work, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: the first (of possibly many) problems you have is that you are using `document.getElementById("root"))` but there isn't any element with the `id` of `"root"` in your HTML

Comment: It might be time to close whatever tutorial you're using, and start anew with a proper modern one that teaches React 18 specifically, because [ReactDOM.render() is deprecated and should not be used](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/render).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a html div with the id='root' to your index.html file like the mentioned in the documentation https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html
So your code will look like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>random-quote-machine</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/babel" src="react.js"></script>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an element with `id='root'` under your `body` tag in your html file to render your React App.

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

Refer [Documentation](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html)